# Post Request via JxBrowser does not hand over data

Tags: url, http-post, jxbrowser

I try a POST Request with the new JxBrowser Version. Unfortunately the data in the body is not handed over.
I guess I am just not using JxBrowser 7 properly.

GET Request does work.

// Post Request

```
 protected void postRequestFromScout(JxBrowserEvent event) {
   String url = event.getUrl();
   Map<String, String> postData = event.getPostData();
   getBrowser().navigation().loadUrl(LoadRequest.newBuilder()
    .setUrl(url)
    .setPostData(toPostDataString(postData))
    .build());
 }
```

// data in POST Request Body as String

```
  protected String toPostDataString(Map<String, String> postData) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (Entry<String, String> entry : postData.entrySet()) {
     sb
      .append(entry.getKey())
      .append("=")
      .append(IOUtility.urlEncode(entry.getValue()))
      .append("&");
   }
   sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
   return sb.toString();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I obviously need to hand over the data in this way:

```
LoadUrlParams.newBuilder(url)
    .postData(toPostDataString(postData))
    .build();
```

As we are using a Compiler based on Java 7 in our Project, this is not a solution for me right now and I will check for another one if possible, but it surely works when used with Java 8.